# How can I improve my simple factory pattern？

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Now I use a singleton factory to create objects. I originally wanted to register with each new class, so I don't need to change the existing factory class, but I am now exposing Class CproductA to the user. How do I design it?

[Coliru Viewer](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f024aecbaca4fc9c)

There are three questions as follows:

1. Class CProductA and class CProductB expose to the user.
2. I need to create the object in advance.
3. m_Map needs to be a global variable.

```
 #include <map>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 //Abstract
 class CProduct
 {
  public:
     virtual void Operation() = 0;
 };

 class CProductA:public CProduct
 {
 public:
     virtual void Operation()
     {
        cout << "Operation A" << endl;
     }
 };

 class CProductB:public CProduct
 {
 public:
     virtual void Operation()
     {
        cout << "Operation B" << endl;
     }
 };

 //Simple Factory
 map <int, CProduct*> m_Map;

 class CSimpleFactory
 {
 public:
    void RegisteProduct(int nId, CProduct* pProduct)
    {
       m_Map[nId] = pProduct;
    }
    void CreateProduct(int nId)
    {
       m_Map[nId]->Operation();
    }
    static CSimpleFactory* GetInstance()
    {
       if(m_Instance)
       {
           m_Instance = new CSimpleFactory;
       }
       return m_Instance;
    }
    void Release()
    {
       if(m_Instance)
       {
           delete m_Instance;
       }
    }
 private:
    static CSimpleFactory* m_Instance;
 };

    CSimpleFactory* CSimpleFactory::m_Instance = NULL;


 int main()
 {
     CSimpleFactory* pSimpleFactory = CSimpleFactory::GetInstance();
     pSimpleFactory->RegisteProduct(1,new CProductA);
     pSimpleFactory->RegisteProduct(2,new CProductB);
     pSimpleFactory->CreateProduct(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revisited [**Factory method pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and found my doubts reasonable:

The factory pattern means to create an instance of a registered class by a certain identification. OP just maps an identifier (index) to a method call of a stored object.

I modified OP's sample a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

First the code for the factory:

```
// factory

class CProduct {
  protected:
    CProduct() = default;
    virtual ~CProduct() = default;
    CProduct(const CProduct&) = delete;
    CProduct& operator=(const CProduct&) = delete;

  public:
    virtual void operation() = 0;
};

class CFactory {
  public:
    typedef std::string Id;

    static CFactory& get() // Meyers Singleton
    { static CFactory factory;
      return factory;
    }
  private:
    // a table mapping IDs to products
    typedef std::map<Id, CProduct*(*)()> Table;
    Table _table;
  private:
    CFactory() = default;
    ~CFactory() = default;
    CFactory(const CFactory&) = delete;
    CFactory& operator=(const CFactory&) = delete;

  public:
    void registerClass(const Id &id, CProduct*(*pFuncNew)())
    {
      _table[id] = pFuncNew;
    }

    CProduct* create(const Id &id) const
    {
      const Table::const_iterator iter = _table.find(id);
      return iter != _table.end()
        ? (iter->second)() // call function to create instance
        : nullptr; // ERROR! Unknown ID.
    }
};

// helper function template
template <typename CLASS>
CProduct* newProduct() { return new CLASS; }
```

then some products which shall be created in factory:

```
// products

class CProductA: public CProduct {
  public:
    virtual void operation() override
    {
      std::cout << "CProductA::operation()\n";
    }
};

class CProductB: public CProduct {
  public:
    virtual void operation() override
    {
      std::cout << "CProductB::operation()\n";
    }
};

void initProducts(CFactory &factory)
{
  factory.registerClass("A", newProduct<CProductA>);
  factory.registerClass("B", newProduct<CProductB>);
}
```

finally the application which uses the factory with products:

```
// application

int main()
{
  CFactory &factory = CFactory::get();
  initProducts(factory); // to prevent this call is hard to achieve
  // input sequence
  const std::string input[] = {
    "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C"
  };
  // create instances for input by factory
  std::cout << "Create products:\n";
  std::vector<CProduct*> products;
  for (const std::string &id : input) {
    CProduct *const pProd = factory.create(id);
    if (!pProd) {
      std::cerr << "Unknown product type '" << id << "'!\n";
    } else products.push_back(pProd);
  }
  // do something with created products
  std::cout << "Use products:\n";
  for (CProduct *const pProd : products) {
    pProd->operation();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Create products:
Unknown product type 'C'!
Use products:
CProductA::operation()
CProductB::operation()
CProductA::operation()
CProductA::operation()
CProductB::operation()
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f80a213c0047bf9f)

Concerning OPs specific questions:

> 1. Class CProductA and class CProductB expose to the user.

Not necessarily. Imagine that the part after `// factory` is one library, the part after `// products` another library. The application (the third part after `// application`) doesn't need to "know" anything of `// products` except `void initProducts()`. So, everything else doesn't need to be exported from library.

This is even good for some kind of plug-in implementation.

> 2. I need to create the object in advance.

No. In my implementation, only a create function is needed.

> 3. m_Map needs to be a global variable.

It needs to be a global if the factory is implemented as singleton. That might be convenient for an application programmer and I would prefer this in such and similar situations.

As well, `CFactory` might be instanced as non-global. However, after creation of factory the registration of classes to create has to happen as well (in my case call of `initProducts()`). That's why I said before *it might be convenient* (for the application developer) to provide a singleton for the factory.

**Note:**

To store the creation function in `CFactory`, I used a function pointer `CProduct* (*pFunc)()` – a pointer to a function without any arguments returning a pointer to `CProduct`. Alternatively, I could have used [`std::function<CProduct*()>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (and in production code, I probably had). While the function pointer may address plain functions only (sufficient in this example), `std::function` might address any callable with that signature, including functors and capturing lambdas. In our production code, this has shown valuable as some of our produced objects depend on extra arguments which have to be bound in class registration of factory.