# Can I create a pointer of a type that is determined at run time in C++?

Tags: c++, types

Is there a way (or function) in C++ to create pointers of type that is determined at run time.
Example:
There is a pointer `*ptr` of type Base.
`Base *ptr=new Base();`
Suppose we have a function `getType` capable of returning type of the pointer passed as its argument.
`getType(ptr)` which returns the type of the pointer so that I can use it to create pointers of similar type like

```
getType(ptr) *newPtr=new getType(ptr)();.
```

Is there anyway in C++ to do this?

Comment: Remember that C++ is not only strongly typed, but also *statically* typed: All types must be available and known at compile-time. Depending on your problem you could possibly solve it though tagged structures/unions, [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) (or their Boost equivalents), or similar type-punning or type-erasure techniques.

Comment: The only way I can think of is if you made your own class's. With a base class and different classes inheriting from base. Then you could have a `getType` method that gets overwritten by each subtype. but I don't believe this is good practice.

Comment: The closest you could get to `getType(ptr) *newPtr=new getType(ptr)();.` would be implementing your own inherited class's as mentioned above. Then having a bit if / switch case to find which type (of a finite amount of options) it is. Again, this is not recommended.

Comment: There are basically no types at runtime, they are purely a compile-time construct. The only (limited) remains of the type system at runtime are `virtual` function dispatch and some type infos. BTW: What you're trying to implement is known as "factory pattern". Just search the web for these keywords to find out more. Further, this seems to be an "xy problem", where you're asking about an unavailable solution to your actual problem.

Comment: There is optional RTTI but many people disapprove of it and say it yields programs that are essentially unmaintainable. So it shouldn't be done. And some resulting void* would lose that information too.

Comment: A sample for the factory pattern: [SO: How can I improve my simple factory pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57505653/7478597).

Comment: Is `decltype(ptr)` what you are looking for? The type still has to be known at compile-time though, but in your example it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy solution that matches your requirement.

Simply replace in your example

```
getType(ptr) *newPtr=new getType(ptr)();
```

`getType` by `decltype`. That is all. Or, I do misunderstand your question.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string answer{};
    int i{};

    // Equivalent to your pseudo code: 
    // getType(ptr)  *newPtr           = new getType(ptr)();

    decltype(answer) *newAnswerPointer = new decltype(answer)();
    decltype(i)      *newIPointer      = new decltype(i)();

    // Assign values to the new types
    *newAnswerPointer = "The answer is: ";
    *newIPointer = 42;

    // Show result
    std::cout << *newAnswerPointer << *newIPointer << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

I just saw that user "super" also mentioned decltype. Becuase he was first. All credits go to him . . .